# jsTree, hover_node, event

Tags: javascript, jstree

The jsTree hover_node callback doesn't return the original (`'mouseenter'`) event.
I'd like to get the mouse position (`Client.Y`) from the event.

Any suggestions, which don't involve hacking the core?

thanks,
BBZ

Answer (score 1):

After going through the documentation I thought about writting a plugin.

```
$.jstree.plugin('custom-plugin', {
  _fn: {
    hover_node: function () {
      console.log(arguments);
      this.__call_old();
    }
  }
});
```

This could be a start (for future reference).
But the argument passed was a node not the event.

Finally I thought of binding to the `mouseenter.jstree event`.
Which gives me the original event.